# Booting up Teradata express VM using VirtualBox

Tags: teradata

I downloaded the Teradata express VM today.  But I don't use vmware... i use virtual box instead. I created a new VM and added all the vmdk disk files to virtual box.

[image]
but it is throwing error could not find /dev/disk/by-label/ROOT-BE1. Want me to fall back to /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00

does anyone know how to boot the vm image with virtual box?

[image]

Comment: a nota bene, VmWare allows to download a free version of VmWare WorkStation for non-commercial use. Might be faster to download the W/S and make your VM run in it straight next.

Comment: I use virtual box. the problem is that different virtual machine engines don't play well with one another. I have seen that installing vmware on the same machine as virtual box creates problems so its better to have only one

Comment: may be. Then install the VmWare WorkStation inside your preferred Hypervisor or vice-versa to have the outer system using a single virtualisation manager ( Using VmWare this way since 1998/9 to have many parallel Universes side by side -- it can even wrap your current system and put it inside a new VM, to be able to migrate your current system inside-out / outside-in )

Comment: Don't create a new VM and import the disks. I never used Virtual Box, but there should be a way to simply import the full VMWare image.

Comment: Are you sure the devices you have added are directly compatible with the older ones originally provided in the vmware image?
The thing is; pre-installed OS expects some specific hardware in the machine, when it cannot find that hardware it tries to fallback to default or legacy drivers. Same goes for device specific configurations.
Basically what you are trying to do is to plug out a disk from one system and insert it into another system and expecting the OS to boot. Unless the systems are identical (or directly compatible), it won't happen

Comment: IMO, easiest way is to use original vmware machine. I keep both virtualbox and vmware installed at the same time and have never found any clashes between them. But I have never executed both of them in parallel and I disable the vmware adapters when no vmware machines are running. Try it this way, hopefully it will work for you as well.

Comment: Old thread, but I ran into this issue today with VirtualBox. Selecting grub "single user" option, changing the Storage Control to SCSI and adding all 3 virtual drives to the SCSI, then removing the old SATA controller fixed the problem for me upon reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, with the same message. The same mistake.

The solution is simple. Just change the Storage Controler to SCSI. After this, restart the VM and it will start normally, but in command line.

[image: Soliction]

I try, but i can't run the startx command...

Comment: This worked for me, when I also used the grub "single user" option too

Answer (score 2):

Try adding IDE controller and then add the disk as existing hard disk device. This should let you boot into the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this exact error when trying to load the VM in KVM. What seemed to fix it was selecting 'single user mode' in the grub menu. After booting like this once, selecting the default grub option subsequently allowed the VM to boot further than this error.

Note that I haven't been able to successfully bring up the actual database yet - the service doesn't start automatically, and when I start it manually, it reboots the VM, bringing me back to the same state as before. Maybe you'll have more luck with VirtualBox?